# How to correctly initialise function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

I want to create a pointer for a function and create a function to initialise this pointer. I'm new to C and can't find example for my problem.

What I have done :

myFile.c :

```
#include "myFile.h"

void (*PT_MyFunction)(int, bool) = NULL;

void MyFunction (int a, bool b)
{
    if (PT_MyFunction != NULL)
       return (*PT_MyFunction)(a, b);
}

void SetPt (void (*pt)(int, bool))
{
    PT_MyFunction = pt;
}
```

myFile.h :

```
extern void MyFunction (int, bool);
void SetPt (void*(int, bool));
```

I have errors in `stdlib.h` and I'm unable to fix them. What did I do wrong ?

**Edit :**

I have many errors `stdlib.h: error: storage class specified for parameter 'XXX'`. The `XXX` are variables in this file.

If I comment the line `void SetPt (void*(int, bool));` in myFile.h I have no error. My header must be wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What errors? Be specific

Comment: There are brackets missing in the declaration of `SetPt()`. Compare with the definition.

Comment: We need more information. Add the full relevant code and the exact error messages.

Comment: Also `null` isn't `NULL`. C is case-sensitive.

Comment: You say you have many errors. Is "*storage class specified for parameter 'XXX'*" the only error message you get? And where is the declaration of `XXX`?

Comment: What is `XXX`? Come on. You have almost 2000 rep. Produce a [mre]

Comment: `My header must be wrong but I don't know how to fix it.` just look at the answers

Comment: Maybe your problem got solved already by the answers. If yes, accept one of these. If not, edit your question to provide the full code and the exact error messages and then @ping me to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the source file

> ```
> void (*PT_MyFunction)(int, bool) = null;
> ```

you probably want :

```
void (*PT_MyFunction)(int, bool) =  NULL;
```

or just

```
void (*PT_MyFunction)(int, bool);
```

because as a global variable the initialization to 0/NULL is done by default

In the header file

> ```
> void SetPt (void*(int, bool));
> ```

must be (without naming the parameter) :

```
void SetPt (void(*)(int, bool));
```

Comment: note that `= NULL` is redundant since static storage duration pointers are initialized to null pointer anyway

Comment: @M.M yes you are right, I edit my answer to say that

Answer (score 1):

The types of parameters in these function declarations

```
void SetPt (void (*pt)(int, bool))
{
    PT_MyFunction = pt;
}
```

and

```
void SetPt (void*(int, bool));
```

are different.

The first function declarations accepts a pointer to a function of the type `void( int, bool )`.

The second function declaration accepts a pointer to a function of the type `void *( int, bool )`.

It seems you mean the following declaration

```
void SetPt (void (* )(int, bool));
```

or just

```
void SetPt (void(int, bool));
```

Within the function definition

```
void MyFunction (int a, bool b)
{
    if (PT_MyFunction != NULL)
       return (*PT_MyFunction)(a, b);
}
```

there is no need to dereference the function pointer. You could write without using the return statement (because the function has the return type `void`)

```
       PT_MyFunction(a, b);
```

Pay attention to that it is not a good idea to redefine the standard macro `NULL` as `null` (provided that it is not a typo).